# (MongoDB) Aggregate (.out) moove values to wrong fields

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregate, mongodb-update

I'm actually creating an autocomplete website bar using express js & mongodb 4.2.7, and using lat & lon to avoid using geocoding api.

Here is the format of my db:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5eea03e9a7891b6d701df571"),
  "id_ban_position" : "ban-position-4c882de48d894fc49ed9be76f7631d6d",
  "id_ban_adresse" : "ban-housenumber-78a2651ce382476ca9c8c8fcbcbaa539",
  "cle_interop" : "01001_A028_5307",
  "id_ban_group" : "ban-group-37c7c3f2b61440b48bca7d8fad56055e",
  "id_fantoir" : "01001A028",
  "numero" : 5307,
  "suffixe" : "",
  "nom_voie" : "Lotissement les Lilas",
  "code_postal" : 1400,
  "nom_commune" : "L'Abergement-Clémenciat",
  "code_insee" : 1001,
  "nom_complementaire" : "",
  "x" : 848436.205131189,
  "y" : 6562595.33916435,
  "lon" : 4.923279,
  "lat" : 46.146903, 
  "typ_loc" : "parcel",
  "source" : "dgfip",
  "date_der_maj" : "2019-02-12"
}
```

as you can see, i got lot of fields that are not necessary for the purpose of my website, and most of all, i don't need to get one row for each number in a street, one unique name of street is enough. So i decided to supress duplicate street name ('nom_voie') and town name ('nom_commune') with aggregate as follow:

```
db.Addresses.aggregate(
  [ {
    $group: {
      _id: {voie: "$nom_voie", commune: "$nom_commune"},
      doc: {$first: "$$ROOT"}
    }
  },
  {$replaceRoot: {newRoot: "$doc"}},
  {$out: 'UniqueIds'}
  ],
  {allowDiskUse: true }
);
```

The problem is that this utilisation mooved a lot of values from one field to an other and made my db absolutely unusable.

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5eea03e9a7891b6d701df571"),
  "nom_voie" : "-",
  "code_postal" : 1400,
  "nom_commune" : "Lotissement les Lilas",
  "nom_complementaire" : "",
  "lon" : 6562595.33916435,
  "lat" : 848436.205131189, 
  "field19" : "dgfip",
  ...
}
```

As you can see, the value of "nom_voie" is now in "nom_commune", "x" value is in "lat", and "y" value is in "lon" and finally the "nom_voie" value is now "-", and i got new fields replacing others ("field19" for "source")...

Am i using aggregate with a wrong option?

I got 47 Millions entry, is this creating some issues?

Thanks to all of you for your time, even if you just reading this!

EDIT :

After few tries and some search i found out that it is the aggregate function that create some problems, but i still don't understand why, if somebody got some hints, i just edited the doc so it's more understandable and readable!
(I thought before that it was a $unset problem in a function)

Comment: which version of MongoDB are you using?

Comment: hey, i'm using mongodb 4.2.7

Comment: I tried installing 4.2.7, inserting that sample document above, and running that update command verbatim.  It seems to have worked as expected without any field shuffling.  Do you have any code that can demonstrate the problem?

Comment: i'm not really sure what i could add to that :/ but if it can help i'm using data from this site https://adresse.data.gouv.fr/donnees-nationales. Some rows seems okay but others aren't at all

Comment: You should try querying the database with the data that you think is wrong.  For example `db.Addresses.find({ "nom_commune" : "Lotissement les Lilas" })`, maybe it's incorrect in the first place

Comment: i already check, my db is okay on this point.

Comment: If you run the code multiple times, do you get the same output? for example, does document with `_id: ObjectId("5eea03e9a7891b6d701df571")` always have the field `"nom_commune" : "Lotissement les Lilas",` ?

Comment: I think what you are experiencing is an unexpected behaviour, it could possibly be caused by a bug. You might want to consider [submitting a bug report](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/wiki/Submit-Bug-Reports)

Comment: yes it always occur at every try... do you have an other solution? cause i really need these data to be treated as soon as possible >< I didn't find any solutions on internet about removing duplicates on specific fields comparaison except  something with group & match that seems correct but i cannot find a solution to delete all the results except the first one ...